# ARC not releasing memory when going "back" in navigation controller - and it's slowing down my uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

Part of the app I'm working on involves a UIPageViewController, where each page displays an 'entry' that is stored in Core Data.  An entry includes, among other things, some images that are being compressed and stored as NSData.  Thus, to load these images and display them on a page, I'm using imageWithData, i.e.

```
photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.photo];
```

The problem is that imageWithData is not particularly quick, and so flipping through pages is not as responsive as I would like.  My best attempt at remedying this situation has been to preload a number of the view controllers that are displayed by my UIPageViewController into an array. (Not sure if that's the best thing to do, but there you have it)

So, to clarify, I have a navigation controller, which contains viewControllerA, which then links to viewControllerB - which displays the UIPageView and the entryControllers (one entryController on each page).  The problem is that when I use the navigation bar to go back from viewControllerB to viewControllerA, I want viewControllerB's array of entryControllers to be released from memory.  But, ARC doesn't seem to be doing so.  Therefore, after going back and forth between viewControllerA and viewControllerB a few times, turning a few pages each time, I start to get memory warnings - which ends up clearing the current array of entryControllers, and defeats the purpose of having that array, since the entries then have to be reloaded every time I get a memory warning.

In short, ARC isn't clearing any of the memory I've allocated for viewControllerB when I go back to viewControllerA via my navigation controller.  I don't like that.  If anyone could suggest a reason that this is happening, or let me know if I'm going about this whole thing the wrong way, it would be hugely appreciated.  I'm just trying to speed up the transition from one page to the next!

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason for ARC to not release your memory is that you still are retaining it somewhere.  Only you know where that is.

Usually, this is caused by a retain cycle, which can happen easily with blocks.

However, it is just as likely that you are keeping a pointer to the object someplace, in a controller, an iVar, or some collection.

Have you run the static analyzer on your code?  It's pretty good at finding some of those things.

What does instruments tell you?  It's got some neat tools for finding leaks and retain cycles.

**EDIT**

You can have as many references to any object that you want.  Once the count goes to zero, it will be released.

The problem is that you are holding an array of strong pointers to view controllers as a cache.  If you want them released, you have to manually nil those pointers.  You are somehow pre-loading controllers into an array.  They will stay alive until you unload them.

So, as long as you have a strong pointer to something, it will stay around.

Comment: So I can be sure of the fact that arc should release everything it can when a view controller is taken off the navigation stack?  I have been using instruments - it's what confirmed this memory issue in the first place - and the static analyzer, but sadly nothing has jumped out at me. For now I'll poke around my code for errant pointers.  I appreciate the info.

Comment: the view controllers stored in the array contain references to managed objects...I'm new to core data, and really to iOS in general, but does this reference to a managed object change things?  i.e. could those managed objects prevent the view controllers in the array from deallocating?  My apologies if that seems a silly question..

Comment: If you are not manually managing your controllers, then you should see them dealloc when they are popped.  Put a breakpoint at dealloc, or NSLog when it happens.  Referencing the managed object will keep them from deallocating, but if you are storing pointers to all your view controllers in a separate array, then that's where they are being held.

Comment: yeah, dealloc is never getting called, and it looks like it's all has to do with managed objects, which I clearly don't know enough about.

Comment: viewControllerA has a managed object called Journal as a property.  It assigns this object to the journal property of viewControllerB.  This Journal object contains entry objects (also managed objects), and one of these entries is then assigned to an entry controller.  I won't bother you further after this, but does this explain the problem?  Is it that viewControllerA still has pointers to these managed objects that are being used as properties of other objects?

Comment: So, in other words, a view controller has a strong managed object, which has a strong reference to the view controller?  That is a strong reference cycle.

Comment: Not quite - it's that multiple view controllers are referencing the same managed objects. I'm not sure that should be a problem per se, but there is certainly something up with managed objects that I'm not understanding.  Might have to do with the fact that related managed objects maintain strong references to each other - in my case, the relationship between Journal and Entry might be affecting something

Comment: This was a great learning experience for me - thanks again for the help.

Comment: In my case, the view controllers were not being disposed of, so the pointers were still hanging around. According to documentation for `UIViewController` (under `viewDidUnload` deprecated method), it states: "When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from memory." Additionally: "Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method [`viewDidUnload`] is never called."

Answer (score 1):

Jody's edit, specifically mentioning setting pointers to nil, is what got the ball rolling for me in terms of understanding, and in the end I was able to figure out my problem by setting certain pointers to nil when my "viewControllerB" disappeared.  Along the way, however, I also realized another important point - large images in core data are a huge memory burden, and in iOS 5, this can be remedied by setting an option to allow for external storage.  So for anyone else who's a relative beginner like me and might come across a similar memory problem, this is a key way to limit the amount of memory being eaten by managed objects storing large amounts of data - your images (or whatever large amount of data) are saved to file automatically, without you having to do anything different in code.